# Generic delegate response handlers

Tags: swift, generics, delegates

I've got a class currently something like this

```swift
class Client {

    var responseOneDelegate: ResponseOneDelegate?
    var responseTwoDelegate: ResponseTwoDelegate?
    ...

    func onData(forMessageType messageType: MessageType, data: Data) {
        
        switch messageType {
        case .responseOne:
            let response = JSONDecoder().decode(Response<ResultForResponseOne>.self, from: data)
            responseOneDelegate?.received(response: response)
        case .responseTwo:
            let response = JSONDecoder().decode(Response<ResultForResponseTwo>.self, from: data)
            responseTwoDelegate?.received(response: response)
        }
    }


}

protocol ResponseOneDelegate {

    func received(response: Response<ResultForResponseOne>)

}

protocol ResponseTwoDelegate {

    func received(response: Response<ResultForResponseTwo>)

}
```

With the idea that a class can be one or multiple delegates

```swift
class Handler: ResponseOneDelegate, ResponseTwoDelegate {

    func received(response: Response<ResultForResponseOne>) { }
    func received(response: Response<ResultForResponseTwo>) { }

}
```

This seems to be screaming out to be generalised as there will be quite a lot of responses in this format, but I can't quite figure out how to do it

I've tried using a generic type to make just a single delegate

```swift
protocol ResponseDelegate: AnyObject {
    
    associatedtype T
    func received(response: Response<T>)

}
```

It doesn't seem possible to store the delegates in `Client` in `[MessageType: ResponseDelegate]` so with the idea of the generic delegate I'm not sure how I'd store the references of the delegates? Maybe I'd just have to cast them before calling?

How would you generalise this?

Comment: Does `Handler` handle `Response<ResultForResponseOne>` and `Response<ResultForResponseTwo>` in the same way, or differently? If they are handled differently. I don't see why this should be generalised. If they are handled the same way, can you show how similarly they are handled?

Comment: @Sweeper The handlers are different, that part of the solution I think would look the same. It seems like there must be a way to not have to define a protocol and delegate variable on Client for each was my thinking

Comment: I see. Jjust write only one protocol, with multiple `received` methods, taking different types of `Response`s then. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Sweeper a class may only care about Response two for example, or response 4. So it wouldn't make sense for it to have receive methods for all types of responses if it only needs to listen for one or a few response types

Answer (score 0):

Functions may be helpful here, in cases where you have a protocol with just a single function in it, and few types that implement the protocol.
Here's an example of the idea:

```
class Client {
    var handle: ((Data) -> Bool)

    init(handle: @escaping ((Data) -> Bool)) {
        self.handle = handle
    }

    func received(data: Data) {
        handle(data)
    }
}

let ints = { (data: Data) -> Bool in
    guard let i = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Int.self, from: data) else {
        return false
    }
    print("handle \(i)")

    return true // if handled
}

let strings = { (data: Data) -> Bool in
    guard let str = try? JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: data) else {
        return false
    }
    // handle Strings
    print("handle \(str)")
    return true
}

let intOrString = { (data: Data) -> Bool in
    ints(data) ||
    strings(data)
}

func handleMany(handlers: ((Data) -> Bool)...) -> (Data) -> Bool {
    return { data in
        for handle in handlers {
            if handle(data) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

let intsOrStrings = handleMany(handlers: ints, strings)

let aOrBClient = Client(handle: intsOrStrings)
let aClient = Client(handle: ints)
```